# One To Many relation spring boot, error relation "<xyz>" does not exist

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I try to create a relation between two tables in a Spring Boot Application.
I have the following Code:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "account")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    public class Account {
      @Id
      @Column(name="ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
      private Long id;
      @Column(name="NAME", nullable = false)
      private String name;
      @Column(name="client_id", nullable = false)
      private Long clientId;
      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
      private Client client;
    }

    @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    public class Client {
      @Id
      @Column(name="client_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
      private Long id;
      @Column(name="NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
      private String name;
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      private List<Account> accounts;
      }
```

I always get the error relation "account" does not exist. What could be wrong?

```
  Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "account" does not exist
```

Comment: Reasonably sure the database table does not exist is the actual point of the error message. Maybe the DB its in has not been selected, or the table dropped or does not exist or no password used...  In short , its the database saying it not the java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could fix it changing:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

in the application.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is returned from the DB and converted into a java exception. In fact, you need to make sure that the table `account` exists in the DB.

Comment: The Table account does exist in the DB and it does work when removing the onetomany/manytoone columns..

Comment: I could now even add en entry into the account table on startup but the error still appears

Comment: How do you query it from DBMS? is it created automatically using spring boot? are there any upper-case characters in your table name? Using your code did not result in any failures for me